# Neo4j Cypher: Find exact match to array Node property in WHERE clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a Neo4J Node with an array property, how do I create a Cypher query to return only the node(s) that match an array literal?

Using the console I created a node with the array property called "list":

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ create n = {list: [1,2,3]};
==> +-------------------+
==> | No data returned. |
==> +-------------------+
==> Nodes created: 1
==> Properties set: 1
==> 83 ms

neo4j-sh (0)$ start n=node(1) return n;
==> +-----------------------+
==> | n                     |
==> +-----------------------+
==> | Node[1]{list:[1,2,3]} |
==> +-----------------------+
==> 1 row
==> 1 ms
```

However, my query does not return the Node that was just created given a WHERE clause that matches an array literal:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ start n=node(1) where n.list=[1,2,3] return n;
==> +---+
==> | n |
==> +---+
==> +---+
==> 0 row
==> 0 ms
```

It's entirely possible I'm mis-using Cypher. Any tips on doing exact array property matching in Cypher would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The console is always running the latest SNAPSHOT builds of Neoj4. the version refers to the Cypher Syntax parswer, we will point that out more clearly :)

Now, there has been some fixing around the Array handling in Cypher, see https://github.com/neo4j/community/pull/815 and https://github.com/neo4j/community/issues/818 which problably are the ones that make the console work. This has been merged in after 1.8.M07, so in order to get it work locally, please download one of the latest 1.8.-SNAPSHOT, build it from GITHUB or wait for 1.8.M08 which is due very soon.

/peter

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Your same code works for me in 1.8M07.

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=p9cy6l

*Update:*
I get the same result (no results) in a local install via the web client. Maybe it's a web client issue?

Comment: The results I showed in my question were obtained from Neo4j community 1.8M07 with locally-running server and the Web client. I do see the query turning up the expected result in your link. How do you know console.neo4j.org is running 1.8M07?

Comment: That's puzzling. The version in console.neo4j.org is labeled as current, which I assumed meant M07. It also works in "1.8" and "1.7" (not "1.6") on the console app. I tried it on my local 1.8M06 and 1.8M07 and get your same result... Maybe someone more familiar will chime in.

Comment: And I get the same result running Cypher from Neocons in Clojure against my local server, so that somewhat rules out an issue with the web client (although maybe they both use REST). Very strange that it works on the web app, and I too can't find any documentation on array literals in Cypher.